# How to BecomeFirstResponder UITextField in UITableView

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uitextfield, becomefirstresponder

There are many same questions on stackOverflow.
But I can't resolve this problem.

How to becomeFirstResponder UITextField in UITableView?
I want to do like a below.
Push edit button, then focus on UITextField in UITableView.

```
-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated{
    if (editing) {
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < items.count  ; ++ i ) {
            UITextField * ii = [textFields_ objectAtIndex:i];
            if ([textFields_ objectAtIndex:i] == [NSNull null]) {
            }
            [ii setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
            if (ii.tag == 0) {
            [ii becomeFirstResponder];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I doesn't make sense to have a `UITextField` within a `UITextView`.

Comment: Thanks for comment. Not UITextView but UITableView. It is like a form of Username or password.

Comment: Does the form have a fixed number of textFields?

Comment: Thanks for comment! There are 7 cells and 7 textField.

Comment: I'm sorry! I should write this code in first row!! [super setEditing:editing animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:YES];
    if (editing) {
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < items.count  ; ++ i ) {
            UITextField * ii = [textFields_ objectAtIndex:i];
            [ii setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
            if (ii.tag == 0) {
                [ii becomeFirstResponder];
            }
        }
    }
}
```